# how to copy char* to a vector<char> and retrieve it?

Tags: c++, stl

I have `char *RecBuffer`, `int *packetLength` point to the data and the size

```
int i=0;
vector<char> temp;//copy the buffer
while(i<*packetLength)
{
temp.push_back(*(RecBuffer+i));
i++;
}

    ...do something 

//retrieve it now
RecBuffer = temp ????
```

Comment: What's the definition of `RecBuffer`?

Answer (score 8):

I believe the easiest way to populate the vector is using the constructor:

```
vector<char> temp(RecBuffer, RecBuffer + *packetLength);
```

As for retrieving it back, use the method `data`:

```
RecBuffer = temp.data();
```

NOTE: `data` will only be available in `C++11` in case you do not compile using the new standard, use `&temp[0]` as proposed by @juanchopanza.

Comment: This is by far the best answer. Don't forget the `std::vector::assign` member function if the vector has already been constructed

Comment: @111111 yes but his usecase doesn't seem to need this one. Still it is good that you mention it.

Comment: @111111 Yeah this does not get mentioned. Thank you +1 ;)

Answer (score 3):

You could say

```
RecBuffer = temp.data();
```

or

```
RecBuffer = &temp[0];
```

if you don't have c++11 support.

but you have to beware that the data will get deleted when the vector goes out of scope. You will also get a dangling pointer if the vector gets resized.

Comment: cannot convert from 'std::vector<_Ty> *' to 'char *'

Comment: +1 great that you mention that data only works in `C++11` I forgot to mention that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the constructor of `std::vector` to copy data from the `RecBuffer`:

```
std::vector<char> temp(RecBuffer, RecBuffer + *PacketLength);
```

You can then use `std::vector::data` to get access to the underlying array:

```
RecBuffer = temp.data();
```

Of course, the underlying array does not exist any more once `temp` is destroyed.

Answer (score 0):

Try looking up the methods of `std::vector` to see if there is something useful.

There are some algorithms in `<algorithm>` that are useful.
    `std::copy(temp.begin(), temp.end(), RecBuffer);`

You could do it the long way:

```
const unsigned int length = temp.size();
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < packetLength)
{
    RecBuffer[i] = temp[i];
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I feel it would be safer to perform the following

```
free(RecBuffer);
RecBuffer = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char) * packetLength);
memcpy(RecBuffer, temp.data(), packetLength);
```